# 2-pane IDE for JavaScript/CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, ide, editor, coffeescript

I am looking for a simple IDE that looks like the [coffee2js](http://js2coffee.org/#coffee2js) website:

- 2-pane - CoffeeScript on left, JavaScript on right - live preview
- Simple debugging feature - REPL, breakpoints, stepping

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has plugin Web Essentials that allow transparent compilation of CoffeeScript, so you can open compiled JS and split window vertically etc

Sublime Text 2 has plugin for compiling CoffeeScript as well and also allow splitting screen on two windows.

I personally love all three ( including Webstorm wrick answered about ) and use them depending on the project ( .NET stack in VS2012, other stuff in ST2 and WS )

Comment: Does it do a live-preview while I type like in the coffee2js site or do I have to hit a button?

Comment: I belive you have to hit button, but it seems that you can tweak plugin and trigger it on keypressed or keyup, just check different github.

Comment: Thanks, but still not sure if it does break-points natively on the CoffeeScript? I can always debug on the generated JS but that's not fun.

Comment: Webstorm does not have live preview

Answer (score 2):

The good old vim has a plugin to enable live preview 
https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script if you're looking for a lightweight solution.

```
:CoffeeCompile watch
```

Answer (score 1):

Found one: [Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/previewing-compiled-coffeescript-files.html). Although its a more heavyweight ugly IDE than I would have imagined (looks like its a fork of IntelliJ)

Comment: I think it is *IntelliJ* just with a little different configuration and "wrapping".

Comment: @harke: It is the same IDE platform  , they have dedicated products for almost all platforms/frameworks - IntelliJ, PyCharm, WebStorm PhpStorm etc

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I've tried Komodo, Sublime, Aptana, and others. For front end, javascript-heavy web development, Webstorm is the best.

As you say, @wrick, it has a [live coffeescript preview](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/previewing-compiled-coffeescript-files.html) option.

It also (at least in the latest EAP) has SASS compilation and JSHint integration.